# jQuery if statement always evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking to see if a form has a "file" input and if it has a vlue. The DOM goes like:

```
<form id="form123">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="file">
    </div>
</form>
```

Console

```
console.log($(formId).find('input[type = "file"]').val().length)
// prints 0
```

if statement

```
if ($(formId).find('input[type = "file"]').val().length > 0) {
// run function
```

It always runs the function!

Comment: has returns jQuery object. It is not boolean function, it is more filter.

Comment: `.has()` is not a boolean test, it returns a collection of all the forms that match the `has()` criteria.

Comment: Okay. What about the issue of .val() is always true?

Comment: What does `console.log($(formId + ' input[type="file"]').val().length)` print?

Comment: It prints 0, yet runs the rest of the statement.........

Comment: Ive updated my code to use .find

Comment: Are you able to provide a fiddle? The one I've whipped up at http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/hS388/ seems to work as expected...  are you definitely using the correct form ID, etc?

Answer (score 3):

`.has()` returns a jQuery collection, not a true/false boolean. So use:

```
if ($(formId).has('input[type="file"]').length)
```

`.length` returns the number of elements matched by `.has()`.

Comment: But then I does not bring you much more than `$("#" + formId + " input[type=file]").length`.

Comment: One returns the number of forms that contain any file inputs, the other returns the number of file inputs. Either will work for testing for existence or nonexistence of file inputs.

Comment: Absolutely, I was only wondering about the necessity of `has()` in the first place, especially since the questioner also wants to filter the `<input>` elements by `val()`.

Comment: Not having done a benchmark, I didn't have any reason to prefer one over the other. So I kept the code as similar to the code in the question as possible to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.find()` as it has [better performance](http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs-find).

```
if ($(formId).find('input[type="file"]').length > 0) {

}
```

**Edit:**

And since `.length` is an integer, I would compare it with another numeric value instead of just evaluate it to boolean like in other answers.

`if (3 > 0)` looks more reasonable than `if (3)`, right?

Comment: Re: your last paragraph: In C#, yes. In Javascript, not necessarily.

Comment: Yes. I understand this, and even when I get 0, it still runs as if true. I am going nuts!

Answer (score -1):

the closing `form` tag is actually an open one, did you mean that? try removing the spaces between the attribute name and the value `class='row'`. You can also try `$(formId).find(...)`

Comment: Someone already removed the spaces when they were editing the question. But both HTML and jQuery allow spaces around the `=`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because none of your suggestions have anything to do with solving the problem. Spaces don't affect anything. Using `find` and `has` both work. And the missing close tag won't prevent it from working, because browsers automatically add missing close tags when they need to.

Comment: How would the browser know where to put the end tag? In my test, when it is left as an open tag, everything else up until the closing body tag gets included in the form. While it might not answer the solution directly, fixing undesired bugs or typos was the aim.

Comment: If you have something like `<div><span></div>`, the browser notices that the DIV has been closed, so it automatically closes everything inside it. If you want to suggest fixes to other bugs, they should be in comments, since they don't directly address the question.